# How to use d3 to plot/add node on scatter plot one by one?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I'm pretty new to D3.js and also Javascript. sorry if asking something stupid.
I just went through the tutorial of D3, and now can plot all the data which saved in my **csv-file**.(load by `d3.csv` function)

I'm curious of that is it possible to plot the dot one by one instead of plotting them all by once?

```
var dataset;
d3.csv("testcase.csv", function(data) { 
    dataset = data;
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr({
                    width: w,
                    height: h,
                });

    function draw(data){
        var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(data);

        circle.enter().append("circle")
              .attr({
                  "cx": data["x"],
                  "cy": data["y"],
                  "r": data["r"],
                  "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
              });
    }

    draw(dataset[0]);

    var index = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(index<dataset.length){
          draw(dataset[index]);
          index++;
        }
     }, 1500);
```

This is what I get for plotting dots at this moment, in the csv-file it saved the coordinate of the dot, and also its radius. For example:

`x,y,r
100,100,50
200,100,30
400,300,20
500,400,50
470,800,40
400,600,40`

I'm trying to use `setInterval` function to let it plot the dot one by one, but it didn't plot anything (Including the first one which should trigger by`draw(dataset[0])`)
And also when using `console.log` function to check whether the value is right, it seems totally normal.
[the output of console pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNr2T.png)

what's is going wrong? Thank for your helping :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from Matthew's answer, if you use d3 transitions rather than setInterval then you don't have to build a loop to process nodes individually and also avoid the problem he described (at least on the first pass, add anymore nodes later and you'll need the data key again)

```
     var data = "x,y,r\n"+
"100,100,50\n"+
"200,100,30\n"+
"400,300,20\n"+
"500,400,50\n"+
"470,800,40\n"+
"400,600,40\n"
;

var dataset = d3.csv.parse (data);

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr({
  width: 600,
  height: 400,
});

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(dataset);

circle.enter().append("circle")
  .each (function (d,i) {
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .delay(i * 1200)  // <- this does what you intended setinterval to do
    .attr({
    "cx": d.x,
    "cy": d.y,
    "r": d.r,
    "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
  });

});
;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/7807/

Comment: This seems amazing! really thanks to your answer! I'll try to go through the document and try it later!

Comment: @Casmo This is by far the best solution for your intended goal.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea for a similar solution I was working on. :)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst OK! Thanks for sharing :D

Answer (score 0):

So, you've come across a fairly common logic error being new to d3. Every time you call your draw function, you also re-bind the data. However, in addition to telling d3 about the new data, this also wipes out d3's memory of the old data. Thus, you are effectively telling d3: this new data is truth, forget any data I've told you about in the past.

Ok, the above is a little simplistic.

d3 doesn't actually forget about what you already told it. However, it needs a way of knowing what is new, what already exists, and what is old. To do this, `.data` assigns each datum a key based on its index in the data array. Since every time you bind just a single element, it will always get a key of 0. Thus, d3 never thinks you are asking it to bind something new.

To solve, this, pass a key function to `data`, [as described in in the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data).

Your code should then look something along the lines of:

```
function draw(data, key){
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data, function(d){ return key; });

    circle.enter().append("circle")
          .attr({
              "cx": data["x"],
              "cy": data["y"],
              "r": data["r"],
              "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
          });
}

draw(dataset[0], 0);

var index = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    if(index<dataset.length){
      draw(dataset[index], index);
      index++;
    }
 }, 1500);
```

Does that make some sense? I highly suggest a thorough read of the documentation. It's how I learned and as documentation goes it's very well laid out, easy to follow, as has tons of examples.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'll go through the documentation and try to fix it!